# Why are signals not working for me in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to create a chess board with pieces. Obviously the pieces will need to move and that's where signals come in. I have a drag_piece script that looks like this.

```
extends Area2D

var selected = false

func _ready():
    input_event.connect(when_held)

func _process(delta):
    if selected:
        followMouse()

func followMouse():
    position = get_global_mouse_position()

func when_held(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
        if event.pressed:
            selected = true
        else:
            selected = false
```

The script works fine by itself but the problem comes when I need to create area2D nodes through script like this:

```
var piece_area2D = Area2D.new();
    piece_area2D.name = piece_name + str(rank) + str(file)
    var drag_script = load("res://scripts/drag_piece.gd")
    piece_area2D.set_script(drag_script)
    var piece_sprite = Sprite2D.new()
    var piece_collision = CollisionShape2D.new()
    var collision_shape = RectangleShape2D.new()
    collision_shape.size = Vector2(64, 64)
    
    piece_collision.set_shape(collision_shape)
    
    var spritelocation = "res://images/pieces/" + piece_color + piece_name + ".png"
    piece_sprite.texture = load(spritelocation)
    piece_area2D.position = Vector2((rank * 64) - (64 / 2),(file * 64) - (64 / 2))
    piece_sprite.scale = Vector2(1, 1)
    piece_sprite.z_index = 1
```

This is not the entire script. Everything works fine besides the pieces dragging when i hold down left click.

I tried adding a print statement in the ready function that prints "works" so I know that the script is working fine, and it did print it so I really don't know what the problem is. I read the Godot documentation on signals and searched google for a good hour and something and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to connect `input_event` to the same object, you can instead override `_input_event`.

   For example:

   ```
   func _input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
       if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
           if event.pressed:
               selected = true
           else:
               selected = false
   ```
2. `get_global_mouse_position` is a global position, set it to `global_position` not `position`.

   Like this:

   ```
   global_position = get_global_mouse_position()
   ```

   The local coordinates might have been aligned with the global coordinates for you, but that is not guaranteed.
3. You could simplify the `Area2D` creation by making an scene and instantiating it.

   You can instantiate an scene from code like this:

   *Godot 4*

   ```
   var instance = load("res://path/to/the/scene.tscn").instantiate()
   ```

   *Godot 3*

   ```
   var instance = load("res://path/to/the/scene.tscn").instance()
   ```

   Your scene can have the script set, the collider, the texture, etc.
4. Did you add the `Area2D` to the scene? The code you showed only creates them.

   Presumably you would use `add_child`:

   ```
   add_child(instance)
   ```